# How to avoid violation of checkstyle rule JavadocParagraph in header?

Tags: checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

After an upgrade from 8.2 to 8.23 I'm experiencing  violations for missing `<p>` tags before and after the URL in the license header

```
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version
 * 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions
 * and limitations under the License.
 */

package bla;

import blu;

public class Bli {
```

without changing the code.

I'm not sure whether the violation is correct, i.e. whether the rule should be applied to text above `package` or whether it's a bug.

In case it isn't a bug I'm planning to suggest and option to allow turning of this check more easily.

I'm using checkstyle through Maven 3.6.0 with the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` 3.1.0.

The easiest approach would be to change `/** */` to `/* */` in the license header, but I don't want to have to propose and do the change for a tool version upgrade.

Comment: License should be a comment, not a javadoc. This isn't a valid placement for a Javadoc since it is not a package-info file.

Answer (score 1):

If comment has javadoc identtifier, checkstyle apply all rules to it. Violation is valid.

If you do not want to change header format, please use suppression https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html

Comment: Sure, but our code base that doesn't fail the build with version 8.17, fails with this error in 8.27. Did you change a strict mode setting? We are also failing the build for three other rules that didn't fail before: `SummaryJavadoc` (missing an ending period), `JavadocMethod` (unused @param), and `RightCurlyAlone` (should be alone on a line). Should I file a bug report, or a new question?

Comment: it is better to move discussion to checkstyle's issue tracker, to discuss separate issue separately and see all details of config/sourcefile/..... .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've found the issue tracker [FAQ](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/report_issue.html) and it looks like I need to narrow down whether this is an issue with the library or the plugin. I'll get on that.